# Вывести рандомное значение в textView по нажатию кнопки

Tags: java, android

Нужно вывести рандомное число от 1000 до 10000 в textView  по нажатию кнопки.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.AddRequest;
import com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.LDAPConnection;
import com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.LDAPException;


import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


public class MainActivityAD extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener 
{
Button rnd;
TextView id;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_ad);

        ImageButton buttonBackSet2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonBackSet2);
        buttonBackSet2.setOnClickListener(this::onClick);

        Button Vvod = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Vvod);
        Vvod.setOnClickListener(this::onClickVvod);

        id = findViewById(R.id.ID);
        rnd = findViewById(R.id.rnd);

    }

public void RND(View view, int start, double end)
    {
        int min = 1000;
        int max = 10000;
        int random =  min + (int)(Math.random() * max);
        id.setText("" + random);

    }
```

Но после нажатия приложение вылетает.
Как правильнее реализовать?

ошибка-

````
    Process: com.example.a1111, PID: 25507
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method RND(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton with id 'rnd'
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:479)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:437)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1131)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)```
````

Comment: Приведите весь код, а не частично. И какая ошибка в логах?

Comment: @ArtyMorris, добавил

Comment: Вы указали implements View.OnClickListener, но в коде я не вижу функции для этого, и где идёт вызов RND?

Comment: @ArtyMorris View.OnClickListener на две кнопки, 1 для перемещения на страницу назад, другая для сохранения введенных данных  с EditText

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перепишите вызов

```
rnd = findViewById(R.id.rnd);
rnd .setOnClickListener(v -> {
    RND(1000, 10000);
});

public void RND(int min, int max) { // зачем вам тут view
    int random =  min + (int)(Math.random() * max);
    id.setText("" + random);
}
```

Comment: Все работает, благодарю.
Случаем не знаете как сделать, чтобы введенные данные сохранялись даже после перезапуска устройства?

Comment: @Pakyltek, если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Comment: Используйте SharedPreference. Но это уже другая тема